# Laravel Auth manually login by id

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

I am new to laravel and I am working with a functionality where we insert data in user table with

`DB::insert();`

After that i get last id with

`$user_id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();`

Now I want user to login after register and I am trying to

`Auth::loginUsingId($user_id);`

But its returning me false. I also tried

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
Auth::login($user);
```

Its also return null $user.

Please help...

Comment: Is the table you store your user in called `users` ? in which tables are you doing `DB::insert()` and `$user_id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId()` ?

Comment: @Mike yes its name is users.

Comment: What is the contents of `$user_id` ? and is the user saved in the table with that same id ?

Comment: $user_id is the id the last insert id in users table while inserting record , its returning me id, but the issue in login when i passing this id its returning false

Comment: The [`login`] ( https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/StatefulGuard.html#method_login ) method has no return value. what happens if you dump `auth()->user()` after you performed a login

Comment: its returning null. For yor info I also tried with old users id manually like Auth::loginUsingId(10) then its logging in. May be the issue of fields

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me

```
Auth::loginUsingId(1);
```

Answer (score 6):

Login User:

```
Auth::login($user);
```

check current user is login or not:

```
Auth::check();
```

Answer (score 2):

`Auth:login` returns `void` so you can try something like this to check if user is logged in or not:

```
Auth::login($user);
return [
    'status' => Auth:check()
];
```

`check()` determine if the current user is authenticated or not.

Comment: I checked in your way but its not logging user

Answer (score 1):

Its better to verify the user exist or not from the database then if user exist go for login else redirect to login page with error

```
 $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();

    if( isset($user)){
        // if user exist login
        Auth::loginUsingId($id);
        return redirect()->route('dashboard'); 
    }
    else{
        // user not exist redirect to login with error
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('error', 'Invalid username or password'); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, can you show your user Model?

In the Laravel Docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication) you can see, that your model must be an implementation of the Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable contract.

The *basic* User model looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

and thats working lice expected.